# Rounding in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point, floating-accuracy

```
$a = ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10) == (int)((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

PHP returns false.

Could anybody explain me, why that happens?
First returns 8, second 7.

Comment: If you ever want to delve into the long answer: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Also take a look at my article http://www.exploringbinary.com/when-floats-dont-behave-like-floats/ (see program 2 in particular). (It's basically just more details on the phenomenon described in the answers below, although in a different context).

Answer (score 14):

Quoting the [big fat red warning in the PHP Manual on Floating Point Precision](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

> It is typical that simple decimal fractions like `0.1` or `0.7` cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for example, `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` will usually return `7` instead of the expected `8`, since the internal representation will be something like `7.9`.
>
> This is due to the fact that it is impossible to express some fractions in decimal notation with a finite number of digits. For instance, `1/3` in decimal form becomes `0.3`.
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and never compare floating point numbers for equality. If higher precision is necessary, [the arbitrary precision math functions](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) and [gmp](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) functions are available.

Comment: In particular, only fractional numbers that can be represented in the form `p/q`, where `q` is an integer power of 2 and `p` is any integer, can be expressed exactly, with a finite number of bits.

Answer (score 5):

Floating point arithmetic is not precise. Instead of 8.0 exactly you can get 7.999... which gets truncated to 7 when cast to an integer.

```
echo number_format((0.1 + 0.7) * 10, 20);
```

Result:

```
7.99999999999999911182
```

Comment: It doesn't help that `var_dump((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);` rounds to `float(8)` for output.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

EDIT

```
$a = ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10) == 8;
var_dump($a);

echo '<br />';

define('PRECISION', 1.0e-08);

$a = (abs(((0.1 + 0.7) * 10) - 8) < PRECISION);
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark's response hits the nail on the head, but I think instead of casting you want the round PHP function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 1):

From [The Flaoting-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/) (click for detailed explanations):

> Because internally, computers use a
>   format (binary floating-point) that
>   cannot accurately represent a number
>   like 0.1, 0.2 or 0.3 *at all*.
>
> When the code is compiled or
>   interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that
>   format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the
>   calculation happens.

Answer (score 0):

Because operating on floating point numbers isn't 100% accurate, propably before casting value from expression is something like 7.9999...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the comparison this way:

```
$a = round(((0.1 + 0.7) * 10), 1) == (int)round(((0.1 + 0.7) * 10), 1);
```